# Display XML Code in the UI

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have an XML content that I would like to show the user. Is there a way I can use the browser's XML viewer? I cannot find a control that I can add to my view that can handle this.

Comment: It is now supported out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380041/5846045

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that's provided out the box, but it should be possible to use [jquery.xmleditor](https://github.com/UNC-Libraries/jquery.xmleditor), which looks like it'll meet your needs. Wrapping it in a custom control shouldn't be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

[As of version 1.46](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/bd0ebd8f7cd6d8603eb9e6174c5de84314bd23fb), UI5 comes with a control called [**CodeEditor**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.codeeditor.CodeEditor) which supports visualizing source code of various types (including XML) with syntax highlighting, line numbers, read-only mode, etc..

Run the following example to see it in action:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/codeeditor/CodeEditor",
], CodeEditor => new CodeEditor({
  value:`<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
>
  <Page>
    <!-- This is a comment -->
  </Page>
</mvc:View>`,
  type: "xml",
  editable: false, // read-only
  width: "20rem",
  height: "7rem",
}).placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.ui.codeeditor"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

Internally, the control uses [*Ace*](https://ace.c9.io).

---

[Documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2832a13753f24c9b89a6d5cf6de32d91)